# How to get a solution after stopping a model in docplex?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, docplex

I try to solve a model in docplex(python) and I add a time limit to stop the model; I want return the last upper bound when the model was stopped.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the info stored in solve_details:

```py
mdl.solve_details.best_bound
```